# Prove that $ \ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) /\mathbb{Q} \ $ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra

(a) For $ \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ $  , let $ \ \zeta_n=e^{\large \frac{2 \pi \large i}{n}} \in \mathbb{C} \ $, Prove that $ \ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) /\mathbb{Q} \ $ is finite.

(b) Let $ \ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) =\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)  \subset \mathbb{C} \ $. Prove that $ \ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) \subset \mathbb{C} \ $ is a subfield of $ \ \mathbb{C} \ $.

**Answer:**

(a)

Here $ \ \zeta_n \ $ is the primitive $ \ n^{th} \ $ root of unity.

We know that $ \ [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n): \mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n) \ $ , weher $ \ \phi \ $ is euler phi function.

Since $ \ \phi(n) \ $ is finite , we can conclude that $ \ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) /\mathbb{Q} \ $ is finite.

I have still confusion.

**But I can not answer part** $ \ (b) \ $

Help me  with part (b) and also verify part (a) answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution to (a) seems to say "$\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)/\Bbb Q$ is a 
finite extension since we already know it's a finite extension".

For (b), the crucial observation is that for $m$ and $n$ there is some $t$ such that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)\cup\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)\subseteq\Bbb Q(\zeta_t)$.

Can you find a possible $t$?

Comment: Is $ \ t=mn \ $ ? where $ \ m,n \ $ are coprime

Comment: Indeed, $mn$ works! @yourmath

Comment: Then  how  $ \ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) \ $ would be  a subfield of $ \ \mathbb{C} \ $? I can 't conclude it. Help me

Comment: To show it's closed under addition/multiplication, take two elements: one is in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$ the other in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$ for some $m$, $n$. Their sum and product must be in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{mn})$.